# Can we move the "Answer your own question"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, self-answer

Above the button that says "Post Your Question" when asking a question.
I feel this looks a bit odd:

> [image]

As the action of "Post Your Question" would actually take you away from this page.  I would think that this would be an option, to say "hey yes before I post this question I'd like to answer my own question".  Something along the lines of this:

> [image]

I'm not a UX expert but the first screen shot just has an odd look to it, it's almost as if the action (posting the question) would come before me answering my question.

Reason being here is when you do check this checkbox "Answer your own question.." the button appears as it should at the bottom of the screen.  So the button being in the middle of two check boxes not only looks odd but doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Especially on an edit...I thought the same exact thing...Can people please stop doing things like that, it adds no value as this was and is a serious request.  There were already arrows pointing to the issues at hand, yet when I looked at the edits the actual images were changed.

Comment: @Jon sorry! But it's *meta*! You can rollback the edit if you think it makes it less serious :/ Sorry again!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ there is meta fun and there is too much.  Complaining about lack of freehand circles is meta fun.  Actually editing images to add freehand circles is too much.

Comment: I've rolled it back. Freehand are usually ok, but for this it does complicate matters a bit. Now you can more easily see the problem of the "answer own question" tickbox being where it is (and not obfuscated by an angry oval-ish beast :D)

Comment: James exactly why I mentioned it.  Thank you for doing that, now it's clear what I am after.  Thanks again

Comment: @psubsee sorry...